# django simple history - how to create history when the object is not created in admin

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I'm using django-simple-history==1.9.0 package with django 1.8.
When I create an object outside the admin and then look at the history of the object in the admin page, it shows a message

> This object doesn't have a change history. It probably wasn't added
>   via this admin site.

I tried setting the user for that object:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='john')
Poll.objects.get(id=536).history.update(history_user=user)
```

but that did not solve the problem.

```
Poll.objects.get(id=536).history.all().count()
```

returns 1 so there is a history generated.
Any ideas how to make it show the history or how to create an additional history?
I also tried [update_change_reason](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) but that did not work at all.

Answer (score 4):

**Assuming your django-simple is correctly configured, follow the procedures below**

In the **`model.py`** file of the app you want to change import **django-simple-history**, the following excerpt for import:

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords
```

In the **`model.py`** file, add the historical attribute as follows:

```
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

In order for your changes made outside of admin to appear in Django admin, simply add the following code in the **`admin.py`** file:

Import:

```
from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin
```

Use the register to configure admin history:

```
admin.site.register(Pool, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

Example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin
from .models import Pool

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Tag, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

After this your history will appear in the admin.

Sources:

https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html

https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html

Regards,

Felipe Dominguesche

Web Developer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I need to create the log in the LogEntry as in the example below because django-simple-history does not track changes outside the admin page:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntryManager, ADDITION, CHANGE
user_id = User.objects.all()[0].id
content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get(model='color').id
object_id = 4
object_repr = 'Color object'
action_flag = CHANGE
change_message = 'you changed it!'
LogEntry.objects.log_action(user_id, content_type_id, object_id, object_repr, action_flag, change_message=change_message)
```